# AngularJS route with params fails

Tags: angularjs

This is my route.js:

```
var app = angular.module('tradePlace', ['ngRoute', 'tradeCntrls']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($route, $location) {
    $route.
    when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/index'
    }).
    when('/index', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/index.html',
        controller: 'indexCntrl'
    }).
    when('/register', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/register.html',
        controller: 'registerCntrl'
    }).
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/home.html'
    }).
    when('/registerCompleted/:email', {
        templateUrl: './includes/templates/registerCompleted.html',
        controller: 'activationInstrCntrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });

    $location.html5Mode(true);
}])
```

And this is activationInstCntrl:

```
var app = angular.module('tradeCntrls');
app.controller('activationInstrCntrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $route){
    $scope.email = $route.email;
}])
```

And the template:

```
hi {{email}}
```

When I go to `mysite.com/` the router does his job but when I go to `mysite.com/registerCompleted/hi` I get a blank page and some weird errors in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < routes.js:1 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < loginService.js:1 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < registerService.js:1 Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token < indexCntrl.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected token < registerCntrl.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   token < activationInstrCntrl.js:1 Uncaught object

I have search but I can`t find why I get the errors and what the solution is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your backend try to find another path

try to join the url by using an anchor (#) or you have to define rules in htaccess

Comment: Can you provide an example on "join url using an anchor", please?